# (Windows) Reading the boot sector of disks with C

Tags: c, windows, file-io, io, bootloader

I am trying to read the boot sector of my disk with C. I am planning to modify the code to use it for other disks such as USB flash drives. I tried this code as a test:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){
  FILE *fp;
  char buf[512];

  fp = fopen("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", "rb");
  int r = fread(buf, 1, 512, fp);
  printf("Elements read: %s", r);
  sleep(3);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it and run it, I get (literally) `Elements read: (null)`.
If I run it as administrator, I instead get `Elements read:`  .

Why am I not able to read the boot sector correctly, and how can I fix the code?

Running on Win10 with MinGW GCC.

Comment: `r` is not a string.

Comment: You're trying to print an `int` with the `%s` specifier. Use `%d`. You also need to check if `fopen` fails and act accordingly.

Comment: What is the sleep supposed to do?

Comment: @Anders It keeps the cmd window open so I can see the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `r` is the number of characters read, and you treated it like it was a pointer to a C-style string. To have even a chance of working, you'd need to pass `buf`, not `r`, to your `printf` call, or change `%s` to `%d` so you're printing the integer value, not trying to treat it as a pointer to a string. The failed read (when you lack permissions) returns 0, which `printf` helpfully displays as `(null)` rather than segfaulting; the successful read returns an integer that when treated as a pointer points to a garbage address that might just barely be readable, but happens to contain nothing but `NUL` characters, so nothing is printed.

Second, assuming you wanted to see the data, not just get a count of bytes read, odds are the boot sector includes `NUL` characters early on that will cause the `%s` scanning to assume the string is already done. If you want to look at the data, either `fwrite` it to some other file for inspection, or encode it, character by character, as hex and write that to `stdout` for human reading.

Comment: My god I am stupid for not using `%d`! I guess I'm tired or something. When I changed it, it showed 0 as nonadmin and 512 as administrator .